# Reading a fasta file format into python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file with the following format:

```
>seq1
ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG
>seq2
ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC
>seq3
AACGTCGTGACGGGTGCGTGGTGTGTGTCCAA
```

I want to read this file as a dictionary in Python. I am aware of BIO-python functions but I want to learn scripting in python in addition to getting my job done. I have tried this code so far:

```
import sys
sequence = ' '
fasta = {}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_one:
    file_one_content = file_one.read()
    for line in file_one_content.split("\n"):
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        if line.startswith(">"):
            sequence_name = line.rstrip('\n').replace(">", "")
        else:
            sequence = line.rstrip('\n')
        if sequence_name not in fasta:
            fasta[sequence_name] = []
        fasta[sequence_name].append(sequence)
print fasta
```

I get the following output:

```
{'seq3': ['ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC', 'AACGTCGTGACGGGTGCGTGGTGTGTGTCCAA'], 'seq2': ['ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG', 'ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC'], 'seq1': [' ', 'ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG']}
```

My expected output file is:

{'seq3': ['AACGTCGTGACGGGTGCGTGGTGTGTGTCCAA'], 'seq2': ['ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC'], 'seq1': [ 'ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG']}

I have been trying to understand why the dictionary is printed in a wrong way but I can't find the mistake. As I want to learn, it would be great if you could let me know how I could correct the mistake in my code. Thanks.

Comment: What was your expected output?

Comment: Please show us actual input file and expected output for that input file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed. There was a problem with your if/else logic.

```
import sys
fasta = {}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_one:
    for line in file_one:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if line.startswith(">"):
            active_sequence_name = line[1:]
            if active_sequence_name not in fasta:
                fasta[active_sequence_name] = []
            continue
        sequence = line
        fasta[active_sequence_name].append(sequence)

print fasta
```

---

python fasta.py input.txt
    {'seq3': ['AACGTCGTGACGGGTGCGTGGTGTGTGTCCAA'], 'seq2' ['ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC'], 'seq1': ['ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG']}

Answer (score 7):

Using biopython SeqIO and a dict comprehension:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
seq_dict = {rec.id : rec.seq for rec in SeqIO.parse("myfile.fasta", "fasta")}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your intention is to learn Python, I will dare to edit your code just a bit and explain it a little.

```
import sys
from itertools import imap

fasta = {}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_one:
    for line in imap(str.rstrip, file_one):
        if line.startswith(">"):
            sequence_name = line.lstrip(">")
        else:
            fasta.setdefault(sequence_name, []).append(line)
```

First of all, file objects are iterators, so you don't really need to read them in (via the `file.read()` method) if you only need to do it once. Secondly, you don't need to specify "\n" in the `rstrip` call. Moreover, instead of calling `rstrip` in several places, you can use `imap` (`map` in Python 3) to lazily strip all lines in one place. And you can just use the `dict.setdefault()` method in order to avoid manual key-check.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to definitely use `dict.setdefault()` from now on, very useful point.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict`using lines that start with `>` as the keys and call next on the file object to get the sequence:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fasta = defaultdict(list)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_one:
    for line in file_one:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            fasta[line.strip(">\n")].append(next(file_one).rstrip())
print fasta

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'seq1': ['ATGGGTGTGTGTGTG'], 'seq2': ['ATGTGTTTGTGTGCTCCTCCTC'], 'seq3': ['AACGTCGTGACGGGTGCGTGGTGTGTGTCCAA']})
```

Which can simply become a dict comprehension:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_one:
    fasta = {line.strip(">\n"):next(file_one).rstrip() for line in file_one}
    print(fasta)
```

Unless you have repeating keys or empty lines a lot of your code is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is not the order that matters, what I don't understand is that why the key and value pairs are not printed out correctly. That is I want each key (seq1, seq2 and seq3), gets only one value (the immediate line after them) as the values.